# Printing new line with TextOut function

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to print a new line with `TextOut` function.

I tried

```
TextOut(hDC, 10, 20, "Hello\nWorld", strlen(text));
```

But the output is "HelloWorld".

How can I print new line with `TextOut`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple. `TextOut` does not have any formatting capabilities. Use `DrawText` instead. See formatting flags to center text, calculate rectangle and so forth. You do not have to use `DT_EDITCONTROL` flag to accomplish `DrawText` formatting. For example,

```
HDC dc = ::GetDC(0);
RECT rc;
char *lpsz= "Hello\r\nWorld";
::SetRect(&rc,0,0,300,300);
::DrawText(dc,lpsz,::strlen(lpsz),&rc,DT_LEFT | DT_EXTERNALLEADING | DT_WORDBREAK);
::ReleaseDC(0,dc);
```

Comment: In `TextOut` function i just give the x and y coordinates. Now it is hard to positioning the text with `DrawText`. But i'll try to use to it.

Comment: @CanVural You do the same with SetRect... just look at the third and fourth parameters. They are X - Y for the "area" of drawing.

Answer (score 2):

TextOut does not format special chars like carriage return, you could use DrawText instead?

Answer (score 1):

All you can do with TextOut is call it everytime you need a new line and increase y coordinate according to settings like font size and printer selected (If chosen printer is "Generic / Text Only" in FILE port just leave it one by one). Otherwise text will scramble if it just not appears at all. With that in mind this function is suitable for plain text intentions and knowing exactly the length of text considering font attributes. So the best use is for a POS printer or using a monospace font, leaving all the text wraping operations to your concern.

```
int
    increment,
    y;
char
    *text,
    *text0;
increment=25;
y=0;
text="Hello";
text0="World";
TextOut(hDC,10,y+=increment,text,strlen(text));
TextOut(hDC,10,y+=increment,text0,strlen(text0));
TextOut(hDC,10,y+=increment,"",0);
TextOut(hDC,10,y+=increment,"",0);
```

Comment: Better idea to get the 'increment' from Windows instead of guessing. See other answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Agree DrawText is preferred.

```
var
  idxRow    : integer    ; // loop counter
  strRow    : string     ; // string version
  strOut    : Ansistring ; // output buffer
  ptrOut    : PChar      ; // pointer to output buffer
  intOutLen : LongInt    ; // length of output data
  objRct    : TRect      ; // area to draw into
  intRowOfs : LongInt = 0; // how far down the window we want to draw into
  intRowHit : LongInt = 0; // how much vertical space was taken up by the output
begin // the procedure
  for idxRow  := 1 to 5 do begin                                // run the demo this many times
    Str(idxRow, strRow);                                        // convert loop counter from integer to string
    strOut    := 'Hello World row ' + strRow;                   // prepare        the output data
    ptrOut    := PChar (strOut);                                // get pointer to the output data
    intOutLen := Length(strOut);                                // get length  of the output data

    SetRect(objRct, 0, intRowOfs, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);   // set the area to draw into, at next row and left edge
    intRowHit := DrawText(intDC, ptrOut, intOutLen, objRct, 0); // draw the output into the area with default formatting
    intRowOfs := intRowOfs + intRowHit;                         // increment row offset by whatever line-height was returned by DrawText
  end;                                                          // done with demo
end; // the procedure
```